# Fix incorrect related posts code snippet

Tags: php, categories, wp-query, actions

Can anybody fix this incorrect related posts codes snippet?

```
function related_posts() {
if (is_single()) {
    global $post;
    $current_post = $post->ID;
    $categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category) :
    ?>
<div class="my-related-posts"><h4>Related Posts</h4><ul>
    <?php
    $posts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category='. $category->term_id . '&exclude=' . $current_post);
foreach($posts as $post) :
    ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?><?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
    <?php
        }
    wp_reset_query();
}
add_action( 'genesis_after_post_content', 'related_posts' );
```

This snippet works fine to display related posts specifically for parent category. Problem is happening after publishing a post under child category (like under “Social Media -> **Facebook**”. # Related posts being displayed twice one for parent and other for child category. Which i don't want.

[image]

Related posts should specifically show based on that particular category, that under the post is published no matter whether it's parent or child category. Can anybody help me regarding this ? Any help would be appreciated  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem:

Try to write down what you want to do: You do not want to print posts that are already printed.

So you have to remember what posts are already printed. In PHP normally an array is a good solution to remember things that are already done. Let's add an array:

```
$printed_posts = array( $current_post );
```

The ID of the current post is added because this post should be excluded always.

Now you have to add the printed posts to that array too:

```
array_push( $printed_posts, $post->ID );
```

But what to do with that array? You want to exclude the already printed posts from your query. That's easy because you got an option `exclude=` to do that. So lets exclude the already printed posts from the query:

```
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category='. $category->term_id . '&exclude=' . implode( ',', $current_post ); // excludeded posts as comma separeted list
```

Befor continue reading, try to insert this advice into your code at the right place. That's the way you will learn how to solve problems.

If you only search for an copy&paste solution, here we go (untested, I don't like such a code mess):

```
<?php

function related_posts() {
    if (is_single()) {
        global $post;
        $current_post = $post->ID;
        $categories = get_the_category();

        foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $printed_posts = array( $current_posts );

        ?>
            <div class="my-related-posts">
                <h4>Related Posts</h4>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    $posts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category='. $category->term_id . '&exclude=' . implode( ',', $current_post );

                    foreach($posts as $post) {
                        array_push( $printed_posts, $post->ID );
                        ?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php

        }

        wp_reset_query();

    }
}

add_action( 'genesis_after_post_content', 'related_posts' );
```

For your second problem, you can ask Google or any other search engine with something like 'get post category' or 'get post parent category'

Answer (score 0):

Tnx mate for taking time to write for me. It’s so nice of you. I tried it but unfortunately it still shows an error :(

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in functions.php on line 84

It's referring to the flowing line:-

`$posts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category='. $category->term_id . '&exclude=' . implode( ',', $current_post );`